# Rails3 with jQuery toggle - setting the selector context to target an element in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a `Rails 3.2.1` app, with jQuery UI toggle.  I wanted the functionality as displayed here: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/PauWy/472/.

But when I added erb variables to my code, I've lost the ability to target only one element. In other words, when I click on '+' on one item, all the items display 'Add'.

my HTML code:

```
<ul id="menu-items">
    <% @menu_items.each do |item| %>
        <li id="item_<%= item.id %>">
            <div class="trigger"><%= item.name %>
                <div class="menu-item" >
                    <p class="to-do">
                        <span> + </span>
                        <span> - </span>
                        <div class="add">Add</div>
                        <div class="reduce">Reduce</div>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

my Javascript code:

```
$('.menu-item').toggle();  // Initially hide all the items

$('.add').hide();
$('.reduce').hide();

$('.to-do > span').click(function () {
    var ix = $(this).index();  
    $('.add', $(this).parents('div')).toggle(ix == 0);    
    $('.reduce', $(this).parents('div')).toggle(ix == 1);
    return false;
});
```

I'm having a hard time understanding this strange behavior, please help.